# Nested ul li header menu

Tags: java, html

I have a block of code from my project, and i want to call menu from database table that contains menu display name string, here is my code:

```
public static String subMenu(List<Menu> menus, String parentMenuId, boolean isSubMenu){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(Menu menu : menus){         
        if(menu.getParentMenu()!=null && menu.getParentMenu().equalsIgnoreCase(parentMenuId)
                && menu.getActive() == Menu.MENU_ACTIVE){
            String menuId = menu.getMenuId();
            boolean isHasChild = false;

            for(Menu menuChild : menus){
                if(menuChild.getParentMenu()!=null && 
                        menuChild.getParentMenu().equalsIgnoreCase(menuId)){
                    isHasChild = true;
                }
            }

            sb.append("<ul>");
            if(isHasChild){
                sb.append("<li>")
                .append("<a href=\"#\">")
                .append(menu.getDisplayName())
                .append("</a>");
            }else{                  
                sb
                .append("<li>")
                .append("<a href=\""+ contextPath + menu.getActualUrl()+"\">")
                .append(menu.getDisplayName())
                .append("</a>")
                .append("</li>");
            }
            sb.append("</ul>");
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

i dont know where but, i think i misplaced something on my code, so the output are like this

```
<ul>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
</ul>
```

Can anyone tell me, and fix my code to get output like this?

```
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Well ... Move `sb.append("<ul>")` and `sb.append("</ul>")` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this;

```
 public static String subMenu(List<Menu> menus, String parentMenuId, boolean isSubMenu){
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(Menu menu : menus){         
    if(menu.getParentMenu()!=null && menu.getParentMenu().equalsIgnoreCase(parentMenuId)
            && menu.getActive() == Menu.MENU_ACTIVE){
        String menuId = menu.getMenuId();
        boolean isHasChild = false;

        for(Menu menuChild : menus){
            if(menuChild.getParentMenu()!=null && 
                    menuChild.getParentMenu().equalsIgnoreCase(menuId)){
                isHasChild = true;
            }
        }

        if(isHasChild){
            sb.append("<li>")
            .append("<a href=\"#\">")
            .append(menu.getDisplayName())
            .append("</a>");
        }else{                  
            sb
            .append("<li>")
            .append("<a href=\""+ contextPath + menu.getActualUrl()+"\">")
            .append(menu.getDisplayName())
            .append("</a>")
            .append("</li>");
        }

    }
}

sb.insert(0, "<ul>");
sb.append("</ul>");
return sb.toString();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
sb.append("<ul>");
```

and

```
sb.append("</ul>");
```

has been moved out from the loop:

```
  public static String subMenu(List<Menu> menus, String parentMenuId, boolean isSubMenu){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<ul>");
        for(Menu menu : menus){         
            if(menu.getParentMenu()!=null && menu.getParentMenu().equalsIgnoreCase(parentMenuId)
                    && menu.getActive() == Menu.MENU_ACTIVE){
                String menuId = menu.getMenuId();
                boolean isHasChild = false;

                for(Menu menuChild : menus){
                    if(menuChild.getParentMenu()!=null && 
                            menuChild.getParentMenu().equalsIgnoreCase(menuId)){
                        isHasChild = true;
                    }
                }

                if(isHasChild){
                    sb.append("<li>")
                    .append("<a href=\"#\">")
                    .append(menu.getDisplayName())
                    .append("</a>");
                }else{                  
                    sb
                    .append("<li>")
                    .append("<a href=\""+ contextPath + menu.getActualUrl()+"\">")
                    .append(menu.getDisplayName())
                    .append("</a>")
                    .append("</li>");
                }
            }
        sb.append("</ul>");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I make it an answer:

Move `sb.append("<ul>")` and `sb.append("</ul>")` outside of the loop:

```
sb.append("<ul>");
for (Menu menu : menus) { ... }
sb.append("</ul>")
```